# how to redirect the user from function that calls function that returns pageReference?

Tags: apex

i have the register function that returns void and from there i call a function that returns pageReference. i attached the register function to the command button in the view but it not redirect me to other page. only when the register function returns pageReference it works.
how can i redirect from the other function?
thanks.

```
public class registerController {
    public String userName {get;set;}
    public String fullName {get;set;}
    public String adress {get;set;}
    public String redirectUrl {get;set;}
    private String errorMessage;

    public registerController(){
        userName = '';
        adress = '';
        fullName = '';
        redirectUrl = '';
        errorMessage = '';
    }

    public void register (){
        try {
            //create new user  
            Customer__c newCustomer = new Customer__c(
                Name = fullName,
                userName__c = userName, 
                adress__c = adress);
            //insert the user to db
            insert newCustomer;
            // redirect the user to shop page
            redirectToShop();                   
        } catch(Exception e){
             errorMessage = 'The User Name You Typed Alrady Exist, Please Choose Different User Name';
             ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL, errorMessage));
        }
    }

    public PageReference redirectToShop(){
        redirectUrl = 'https://c.eu11.visual.force.com/apex/shop';
        PageReference retURL = new PageReference(redirectUrl);
        retURL.getparameters().put('Id',userName);
        retURL.setRedirect(true);
        return retURL;      
    }
}
```

Comment: `public PageReference register(){` and `return redirectToShop()`

Comment: i tryed that but i dont want to redirect if i get exception. i just want show message. that is why i made that function as void becouse it not showing me the message

Comment: Right, if you get an exception, you'd have to `return NULL;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change register() method return type to page reference, return PageReference/Null in try catch respectively

```
public PageReference register() {
    try {
        //create new user  

        //insert the user to db

        // redirect the user to shop page
        return redirectToShop();                   

    } catch(Exception e){
        errorMessage = 'Your error!';
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL, 
            errorMessage));
        return null;
    }
}

public PageReference redirectToShop(){
    // NEVER hardcode URL
    // redirectUrl = 'https://c.eu11.visual.force.com/apex/shop';
    PageReference retURL = Page.shop;
    retURL.getparameters().put('Id',userName);
    retURL.setRedirect(true);
    return retURL;      
}
```

**Never hardcode a URL anywhere, In Visualforce, better would be to use Page.PageName which returns a Pagereference**